# Unix Bash Prevent sed From Merging Lines?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I'm completely new to unix and I'm trying to figure out how to remove lines containing part of a string from a directory of files. I have managed to piece a script together from what I have read, but the problem is that it merges the lines and does not preserve the carriage returns.

**Command:**

```
grep -l "apple" tmp/* -R | xargs -I'{}' sed -i '/apple/d' '{}'
```

**Files:**

```
1.txt
applepie
green
blue

2.txt
applepie
green
blue
```

**Output:**

```
1.txt
greenblue

2.txt
greenblue
```

**What do I need to change in order to keep green and blue as separate lines?**

Note: I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm on Windows using cygwin.

Comment: if MSWIndows was involved at some point with 1.txt and 2.txt, then `dos2unix *.txt`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I don't understand dos2unix merges the lines? I need to keep them separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the commands.  The commands and files in your question are correct, and do produce the output you desire.

The problem you describe is characteristic of the way line endings are treated differently between Unix-like systems and Windows-based systems.  This happened probably because you used a Windows-based tool to create the files, which gave them Windows-style line endings, while the tools in the Cygwin environment expect Unix-like line endings.  Fortunately, there's a handy command you can use to convert all the line endings in the files into the proper type - it's called `dos2unix`.

`dos2unix` converts all the line endings in a file into the Unix/Linux kind. (And, if they're already that way, it doesn't hurt to run it.)  You use it like this:

```
dos2unix *.txt
```

After you do that, the files will have the correct line endings, and your original command should work (but Arif Burhan was right - you can do the same thing just using `sed -i '/apple/d' *.txt`.)

If you like Cygwin, try this thing called [babun](https://babun.github.io/) - it's Cygwin, but with a bunch of behind the scenes setup done to make it easier and more fun to use.

Happy Hacking!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in a comment, this is probably due to how newlines are handled. You can print control characters with `cat -A`; if your file looks like this:

```
$ cat -A 1.txt
applepie^M$
green^M$
blue^M$
```

then you probably have carriage return + line feed as newline characters (DOS/Windows style). Or in a hexdump:

```
$ od -w10 -t az --endian=big -x 1.txt
0000000   a   p   p   l   e   p   i   e  cr  nl  >applepie..<
           6170    706c    6570    6965    0d0a
0000012   g   r   e   e   n  cr  nl   b   l   u  >green..blu<
           6772    6565    6e0d    0a62    6c75
0000024   e  cr  nl                              >e..<
           650d    0a00
0000027
```

where the suspicious `0d0a` and `cr nl` tell you the same story.

To fix this:

```
$ dos2unix 1.txt
$ cat -A 1.txt
applepie$
green$
blue$
$ r$ od -w10 -t az --endian=big -x 1.txt
0000000   a   p   p   l   e   p   i   e  nl   g  >applepie.g<
           6170    706c    6570    6965    0a67
0000012   r   e   e   n  nl   b   l   u   e  nl  >reen.blue.<
           7265    656e    0a62    6c75    650a
0000024
```

Only `nl` (`0a`) for newlines – sed should be okay with newlines now.

Answer (score 0):

You only need:

```
sed -i '/apple/d' textfile.txt
```

Unless you want the output going to another file , when you add

```
> newfile.txt
```

at the end.

Comment: **sed -i '/apple/d' tmp/***   will output to console , as will                      **cat tmp/* | sed -i   '/apple/d'**

Comment: Both of the above work on each file in the   **tmp/** directory.

Comment: I need it to check all the files in a directory. I tried `sed -i '/apple/d' tmp/*` but that still had the same output. I need to keep the lines separate.